# unit testing for aem not covering a condition

Tags: unit-testing, junit, aem, junit5

im new to unit testing. I am using junit5 for an aem 6.5 application. Im trying to write unit test so that i can migrate to cloud which has a requirement of atleast 50% unit test, thus what im doing now. My code has an init method for the getTags(). My unit test works fine but the jacoco reports a line that is not being covered. Any help would be appreciated to pint me in the right direction.

I have this class:

```
@Self
private SlingHttpServletRequest request;

@ValueMapValue
private List<String> tags;

@Override
public String getExportedType() {
    return RESOURCE_TYPE;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Resource tagsNode = request.getResource().getChild("tags");
    tags = new ArrayList<>();
    if (tagsNode!=null) {
        for (Resource child : tagsNode.getChildren()) {
            TagModel tag = child.adaptTo(TagModel.class);
            tags.add(tag.getTag());
        }
    }
}

public List<String> getTags() {
    return this.tags;
}
```

And i have this unit test for aem

```
@Test
void testGetTags() {
    List<String> expected = new ImmutableList.Builder<String>()
            .add("4")
            .add("22")
            .build();

    ctx.currentResource("/content/blog_placeholder");

    BlogPlaceholderModel blogPlaceholderModel = ctx.request().adaptTo(BlogPlaceholderModel.class);

    List<String> actual = blogPlaceholderModel.getTags();

    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

@Test
void testGetExportedType() {
    final String expected = "furniture-row/components/content/blog-placeholder";

    ctx.currentResource("/content/blog_placeholder");

    BlogPlaceholderModel blogPlaceholderModel = ctx.request().adaptTo(BlogPlaceholderModel.class);

    String actual = blogPlaceholderModel.getExportedType();

    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

For some reason my test is not covering the if condition:

[image]

what am i missing ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests are covering this line *partially*.

You do have a test for the case that `(tagsNode != null) == true` but not for `(tagsNode != null) == false`. Therefore, the line is yellow to indicate that not all "branches" of the `if` statement are covered.

Comment: ah youre right, i made a test so that it returns null explicitly and it is all now covered. So if there is a switch statement in a unit test, that will happen again i assume. But good to know :) Thanks